# WPF draw scaled a filled closed Polygon

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a Graph **UserControl** that draws a graph with gridlines.
The user control is designed so the caller adds 1 value at a time and the user control adds it to a bucket containing the last 60 entries. The value is added by setting the TabulaData property. 
**The data elements given are in the range 0.0 - 100.0**

The net  effect is the graph will scroll when new values are added once it reaches 60 elements.

On the left side of the GUI I have a Listbox containing the graphs scaled down. When the graph is selected in the list a full size version is drawn.

**When the full size graph is created it is drawn perfectly. When it is drawn in the Listbox it sometimes draws a line outside of the gridlines and it should NOT.**

The graph is created by creating a closed filled Polygon.
The math I have checked several times and not sure why it draws incorrectly in the Listbox sometimes. In the Listbox the graph is 44x50 which is less than the number of data elements so it is scaled down.

The question is how can I keep the scaled down version from drawing outside the gridlines?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Binding = System.Windows.Data.Binding;
using Point = System.Windows.Point;
using Brush = System.Windows.Media.Brush;
using ToolTip = System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip;

namespace GraphContainer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Graph.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Graph : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Graph()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SizeChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                SafeCreateGraph();
            };
        }


        private bool _drawGrid = true;

        public bool DrawGrid
        {
            get { return _drawGrid; }
            set
            {
                _drawGrid = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private Brush _gridBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0x77, 0x77, 0x77));

        public Brush GridBrush
        {
            get { return _gridBrush; }
            set
            {
                _gridBrush = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private Brush _fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);

        public Brush Fill
        {
            get { return _fill; }
            set
            {
                _fill = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                InvalidateVisual();
            }
        }

        private Brush _stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

        public Brush Stroke
        {
            get { return _stroke; }
            set
            {
                _stroke = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                InvalidateVisual();

                GraphBorder.BorderBrush = value;
            }
        }

        private double _sampleSize = 60;

        public double SampleSize
        {
            get { return _sampleSize; }
            set
            {
                _sampleSize = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                SafeCreateGraph();
            }
        }

        private double _tabulaData;

        public double TabulaData
        {
            get { return _tabulaData; }
            set
            {
                _tabulaData = value;

                TabulaList.Insert(0, value);
                while (TabulaList.Count > SampleSize)
                {
                    TabulaList.RemoveAt(TabulaList.Count -1);
                }
                SafeCreateGraph();
            }
        }

        public void ResetData()
        {
            TabulaList.Clear();
            SafeCreateGraph();
        }

        private readonly List<double> _tabulaList = new List<double>();

        public List<double> TabulaList
        {
            get { return _tabulaList; }
            set
            {
                _tabulaList.Clear();

                foreach (var d in value)
                {
                    _tabulaList.Add(d);
                }
                OnPropertyChanged();
                SafeCreateGraph();
            }
        }

        private void CreateGrid()
        {
            if (ActualHeight  < 1 || ActualWidth < 1)
                return;

            var drawHeight = ActualHeight - 2;
            var drawWidth = ActualWidth - 2;

            var widthscale = Math.Max(10, drawWidth / (SampleSize - 1));
            var yscale = Math.Max(10, drawHeight * .05); // 5 %

            for (var x = 0.0; x < drawWidth; x += widthscale)
            {
                var l = new Line
                {
                    Stroke = GridBrush,
                    X1 = x,
                    X2 = x,
                    Y1 = 0,
                    Y2 = drawHeight
                };

                GraphCanvas.Children.Add(l);
            }

            for (var y = 0.0; y < drawHeight; y += yscale)
            {
                var l = new Line
                {
                    Stroke = GridBrush,
                    X1 = 0,
                    X2 = drawWidth,
                    Y1 = y,
                    Y2 = y
                };

                GraphCanvas.Children.Add(l);
            }
        }

        private string _graphHelpText = "";

        public string GraphHelpText
        {
            get { return _graphHelpText; }
            set
            {
                _graphHelpText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void SafeCreateGraph()
        {
            if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                CreateGraph();
            }
            else
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(CreateGraph));
            }
        }

        private void CreateGraph()
        {
            GraphCanvas.Children.Clear();

            if (ActualHeight < 1 || ActualWidth < 1)
                return;


            if (DrawGrid)
            {
                CreateGrid();
            }

            if (TabulaList.Count > 1)
            {
                var p = new Polygon { Fill = Fill, Stroke = Stroke };
                if (DrawGrid)
                {
                    var t = new ToolTip
                    {
                        DataContext = this,
                        Placement = PlacementMode.Mouse
                    };
                    var binding = new Binding(nameof(GraphHelpText))
                    {
                        Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
                    };
                    t.SetBinding(ContentProperty, binding);
                    p.ToolTip = t;
                    ToolTipService.SetInitialShowDelay(p, 0);
                    ToolTipService.SetBetweenShowDelay(p, 0);
                    ToolTipService.SetShowDuration(p, 120000);
                }

                var drawHeight = ActualHeight - 2;
                var drawWidth = ActualWidth - 2;

                var widthscale = drawWidth / (SampleSize - 1);
                var yscale = drawHeight / 100.0;
                p.MouseMove += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var point = args.GetPosition(p);
                        var time = (int) (SampleSize - 1) - (int) (point.X / widthscale + .5);
                        var tabula = TabulaList[time] / 100;
                        var seconds = time == 1 ? "second" : "seconds";
                        GraphHelpText = $"{time} {seconds} {tabula:P}";
                    }
#pragma warning disable CC0004 // Catch block cannot be empty
                    catch (ExternalException)
                    {
                        // ignored
                    }
#pragma warning restore CC0004 // Catch block cannot be empty
                };

                const int min = 0;
                var xmax = drawWidth;
                var ymax = drawHeight;

                var x = 0.0;
                for (var i = 0; i < TabulaList.Count; i++)
                {
                    var tabula = TabulaList[i];

                    x = drawWidth - i * widthscale;
                    x = Math.Max(min, Math.Min(xmax, x));
                    var y = drawHeight - tabula * yscale;
                    y = Math.Max(min, Math.Min(ymax, y));

                    p.Points.Add(new Point(x, y));
                }

                p.Points.Add(new Point(x, ymax));
                p.Points.Add(new Point(xmax, ymax));

                GraphCanvas.Children.Add(p);
            }

            InvalidateVisual();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without a screenshot. You should however generally set `StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round` on a shape to avoid spiky vertexes. Besides that, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged` on a OneWay Binding is pointless. It only has an effect on TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings. And setting `BindingMode.OneWay` is redundant, because it's the default.

Comment: Changing StrokeLineJoin to PenLineJoin.Round seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Polyline's `StrokeLineJoin` to `Bevel` or `Round` to avoid "spiky" corners.

```
var p = new Polygon
{
    Fill = Fill,
    Stroke = Stroke,
    StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round
};
```